# Eclim is slowing down opens and writes of ALL files from vim

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

Eclim is slowing down open, write and close of ALL files from vim.
I'm using headed Eclipse and console VIM in Cygwin.
just opening a .vimrc file takes 5 seconds.
Writing it takes 5 secs also.
Closing it takes no time, if its already been written.

Maybe I need to tell eclim/eclipse to only "mess" with .java files?

Comment: What's in your vimrc relating to eclim

Comment: Pasted my .vimrc here:    http://pastebin.com/xUDv0dFB